# Primary key: a string or number (id)?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am aware of benefits of using integers (amount of space, performance, indexes) as primary keys as opposite to strings.

Considering situation below...

I have a lookup table called ap_habitat (habitat values are also unique)

```
id   habitat
1    Forest 1
2    Forest 2
```

Referenced table (fauna)

```
Especie  habitat
X         1
Y         1
```

Referenced table is not very human readable (I know end users should not care about that, but for me would be useful to directly see in fauna table the NAME of the habitat).

To get a list of fauna and its habitat name I have to do a join...

```
select fauna.habitat, fauna.especie, AP_h.habitat from fauna INNER JOIN ap_habitat AS AP_h on AP_h.id=1
```

I could create a view, but if I have to create a view for each table referencing a foreign key...

Just wanna check what more experienced people recommend me.

Comment: So you want to store stuff in a database and inspect it without typing queries? That's not what relational databases are meant for. Just write an app on top of the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases and, in general, computers are not designed to make your life more simple. They are designed to handle more data than a human mind can ever hope to remember in less time than it takes a human to blink. ;-)

Readability (especially in ideas conceived the before-Apple age) is not an issue at all.

On top of that: If you enjoy strange problems, data mapping impedance and spending endless nights writing workarounds for problems that using real-world names as primary keys get you for free, then be our guest. But please, don't ask for our help. We already know all the problems that you'll run into and it will be very hard for us to restrain our spite.

So: Never, ever use anything but an ID (UUID or long sequence) for a primary key. There are no (good) reasons to do it and if you found one, then you simply don't see the whole picture.

Yes, it makes a couple of things harder (like understanding what your data actually means). But as I said above, computers are meant to solve "lots of data" and "too slow" and nothing else.

Create a view or write a small helper application that can run your most important queries at the click of a button.

That said, I had some success with an application which runs a query and then displays a list of check boxes where I can pull in the foreign key relations to the data that the query returns (i.e. one checkbox per FK).

Comment: As i can understand that dbs are much faster on ids over string, i dont understand why you totally forbids usage strings as primary keys. DB uses hashes for storing this values and therefore use int comparison - just on several levels more - And as i remember doing btree search is quite fast - just inserting isint (nor updating the index fields) so it shouldnt be much slower but can speed up everything using lower numbers of joins, additional search queries and so on. Please, if you could tell something more why not, i would be grateful.

Comment: UUIDs are strings, so I'm not against strings per se but against something that exists in real life like "habitat names". If such a name changes (and they do, just think of someone making a typo), then you're in deep trouble because in most databases, you can't change PKs easily.

Comment: Oh, ok. Now i understands^_^ (Just thought for a moment everything i check and learned was a bit old already). And yes i have several varchar(128) PK, but i DONT change them at all - they are like UUIDS .

Answer (score 0):

You ask about number or string as primary key.  But based on your example if you use a string it wouldn't be a primary key at all, because you would no longer have a lookup table for it to be the primary key of.  Perhaps you would still have the table for reasons not shown, like populating a drop down or storing extended descriptions beyond just the name.

Doing needless joins is not a good thing for performance.  And having needless tables might be bad for storage size as well, depending on the length of the strings and the ratio of the sizes of the two tables.

You could also consider enumerated types, in which the data is stored as numbers (more or less) but the database translates them to and from strings automatically.